# private method `puts' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, instance, puts

I am not sure why I lose access to the methods of the instance variable when I try accessing it from another method in the class.

The program is a chat program ( in progress). Sorry if this is a noob question, I am trying to brute force learning Ruby from what I already know in other languages.

```
require 'socket'      # Sockets are in standard library

class Client
    def initilize()
        hostname = 'localhost'
        port = 2000
        @s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)   
    end

    def startChat  
        puts "Starting Client"
        message = gets.chomp
        @s.puts(message)

        while line = @s.gets   # Read lines from the socket
            puts line.chop      # And print with platform line terminator
            @s.close               # Close the socket when done
            gets.chomp
        end
    end
end

c = Client.new()

c.startChat
```

Comment: @BorisStitnicky *sigh* Yes, I realized I was opening up too much of a can of worms. In any case, the problem is still a `nil.puts` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sevenseacat spotted the typo.

Comment: As an aside, it is complaining about the private method `puts` because `puts` is in `Kernel` as a private method (along with all the other standard "global methods that are really functions").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your `def initialize()`, so it is not being called when you initialize your Client instance. Therefore `@s` is never being defined (so it is nil).

Comment: Thanks, that is it. I probably should start using a debugger.